# tsconfig.json shows error: Entry point for implicit type library 'glob'

Tags: typescript, react-native, tsconfig, monorepo

I have a Monorepo which uses Typescript. I have a *common* folder which shows this error on the top of the file -> `Entry point for implicit type library 'glob'`. I am not sure what is wrong with the configuration.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
"extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": [
        "es2021"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": false,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "composite": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declarationMap": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
]
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 35):

I just re-started VS Code and the error was gone.

Comment: lol. thank you very much for this, after finding many solutions

Comment: And then 3 minutes later, it came back.

Comment: Yes, exactly that!

Answer (score 13):

Include "types" in your "compilerOptions" ...

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      // ... your other types
      "node"
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: Please explain your response. As it is, it neither answers the question nor clarifies anything.

Comment: I don't know why but this worked for me.

Comment: I don't even know why i had a similar error in the first place but this worked for me too. brilliant

Comment: This is because Typescript defaults to "all visible ”@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible. For example, that means packages within ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/, ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on."
By restricting `types` to "node" it does not traverse all `node_modules` directories. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types

Answer (score 0):

Remember that types are for npm projects that weren't written in Typescript.

So if the library is migrated to Typescript you can uninstall the types.

I just had the same issue with `marked` in an Angular project. Marked is now written in Typescript so doesn't need @types.

```
npm uninstall @types/marked
```

A big clue this may have happened is if the version under @types differs greatly from the project itself.